# link in gridview to details page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

What I'm trying to do is create a `Gridview` and in the grid have a `HyperLinkField` it send me to  a detail page for that item,  I have the part that  filled the grid and the link and how to pass the id of the element to another page

The problem I have is that when I run and click on the link shows me the details page that I want but is blank. when I debugged, I don't reach the details page

here is my code

**fill the grid**

```
var datos =  db.Ticket   
        GridView1.DataSource = datos;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

**show the GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>

      <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Ver Ticket" Text="Ir Historial Ticket" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/DetailTicket.aspx?id={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="IdTicket" />
   </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

**the detail page**

```
public partial class DetailTicket: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
           var id= Request.QueryString["id"];
        var datos =  db.detailTicket.Where(e=>e.IdTicket==id)   
        GridView1.DataSource = datos;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debug code ? which value u will get Request.QueryString["id"]

Comment: (but the problem is when I debug it don't reach to the page_load either ) have you check your url ... its working fine with me and load event fired

Comment: what i debug is the page load of  my DetailTicket it dont reach after i click the link it show me the page 
http://localhost:2509/DetailTicket.aspx?id=1

Comment: in mvc i do like this
 @Html.ActionLink("detail ticket", "index", new { id = item.IdTicket})

an in my page just
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {}

Comment: past that url direct into browser and check is your event is fired

Comment: fu... sorry yes it was for the url i have a folder after have to change this ~/Interfaz/VerTicket.aspx?id={0} in mi code sorry guys :s

Comment: Ok i m posting answer pls up vote and accept answer Thanks :)

Comment: best thing to do here is view the page source and study the hyperlink url always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey it might be issue with your path...

I have test your code and its working fine with me....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets on the `if` statement in the `Page_Load` event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
  {
       var id= Request.QueryString["id"];
       var datos =  db.detailTicket.Where(e=>e.IdTicket==id)   
       GridView1.DataSource = datos;
       GridView1.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Without the brackets, your `id` variable will not be known on the next line. I'd be surprised if it even compiles.

Comment: but the problem is when I debug it don't reach to the page_load either

Comment: @Diego_DX fix the bracket issue and try again. If still doesn't work is not because of the code you posted. Again, I am surprised if you code actually compiles. As it stands, you are referencing a variable that's out of scope. The compiler would complain.

Comment: yep sorry i forget to put the bracket but the problem iam getting is it dont reach the page i want or how i create a page that accept parameter in asp.net ?

Comment: Your code is fine. The way you pass the parameter is correct. You can easily confirm it by looking at the links generated on the grid. I think your problem is elsewhere.